# What is wrong in that javascript/jquery array iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I trying declare an array, push colection of arrays and iterate colection

My JS:

```
var colection = [];
var array = ["a1", "a2"];
colection.push(array);
array = ["b1", "b2"];
colection.push(array);

$.each(colection, function(array){
    var p = "<p>1:"+array[0] +
        "<br>2:"+array[1]+"</p>";

    $("#test").append(p);
});
```

my html:

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

I want that result:

```
1:a1
2:a2

1:b1
2:b2
```

but return only:

```
1:undefined
2:undefined

1:undefined
2:undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the function in the each syntax is actually the index of the item so change the script to look like:

```
var colection = [];
var array = ["a1", "a2"];
colection.push(array);
array = ["b1", "b2"];
colection.push(array);

$.each(colection, function(index, array){
    var p = "<p>1:"+array[0] +
        "<br>2:"+array[1]+"</p>";

    $("#test").append(p);
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9KVnM/

Edit: Ref: [api.jquery.com/jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each)

Thx Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You canned to use key value pair in iteration like;

```
$.each(collection, function(i, array){
    var p = "<p>1:"+array[0] +
        "<br>2:"+array[1]+"</p>";

    $("#test").append(p);
});
```

Here is demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/JJ9UA/2/**